# Is there a no v7.28:0:0 of exitinterface library?

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting an error of All com.android.support libraries must use the exact version specification.

here is where I'm getting the error "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'"

I had `com.android.support:exifinterface-v7:27.0.0` I don't know why it does not have a version 28. please help me T_T

```
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.0.2'

 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
 implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
 implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had com.android.support:exifinterface-v7:27.0.0 I don't know why it
>   does not have a version 28.

This is because exifinterface is [belongs to com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface)

so, use:

```
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"
```

Comment: sorry. I typed the wrong code. it's now working fine. thank you so much btw.